# How to add data to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, google-calendar-api, associative-array

I'm creating 'Calendar of Event' using Google Calendar API for my project.
To add attendees to my specific event, the API needs the data in this format below.

The format I want (by the Google Calendar API):

```
array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
)
```

Now, I have my data in just one dimensional array.
Let's say I get them from some form (which works just fine):

```
$people = $_POST['people'];
```

How can I convert `$people` so that it can be readable by the API?
Thank you. Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_map()` to create an array of arrays from the array.

```
$data = array_map(function($person) { return ['email' => $person]; }, $people);
```

or a `foreach` loop.

```
$data = [];
foreach ($people as $person) {
    $data[] = ['email' => $person];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. @Barmar
But the strange thing is I must assign the $data into some new variable, lets say $finaldata['result'] then I call it to the API to make the whole insert attendee process complete.

Comment: That depends on the API. If it requires everything in a `{result: ...}` object, that's what you have to do.